# Finding the value of 1980 Issued Stock in MCO Resources, a Los Angeles Company

Tags: united-states, stocks

I believe it was an energy company. My mother purchased it for me then. Just discovered the certificate. It has either merged or gone out of business. Can anyone help me trace it? Once the company is found, would this stock still have value? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

MCO Resources Inc was a company listed on Amex from May 1980 until Jul 1988.

In 1980, its stock price was between $7.75 and $14.50.
On its last trading day (6 Jul 1988) it closed at $0.3125.

It was taken over by United Meridian Corp by a cash offer of $0.40 per share.

United Meridian Corp was taken over by Ocean Energy Inc in 1998.
Ocean Energy Corp merged into Seagull Energy Corp in 1999 (which changed its company name from Seagull Eenergy to Ocean Energy Corp)
Ocean Energy Corp merged into Devon Energy Corp in 2003.

Devon still exists today - you should contact them and see if they are able to assist:
https://investors.devonenergy.com/investors/default.aspx

As others have suggested, it's likely the cash offer made to shareholders was probably mailed as a check, so using services offered by National Association of Unclaimed Property Administrators (that operate missingmoney.com and unclaimed.org) might help.

Source:  Internal databases at Norgate Data.

Comment: History is great, but there is absolutely no point in contacting Devon. I doubt anyone would remember a merger 5 levels removed and 30 years ago.

Comment: I'm sure there is a paper trail, but I can't see $0.40 as something worth all the effort it will take.

Comment: On 100 shares, not really.  On more, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Most stock certificates list the Transfer Agent on them, often in the lower right corner.  If it's there, contact them to determine what happened to the company (change of company name and trading symbol, merger, bankruptcy, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The company is probably long gone. The stock however is in your name, therefore if the company went private or merged, you would've been issued a check for the amount the shares were worth or equivalent amount of stock in the merged company.
Assuming you were a minor at the time, your mom probably claimed the money in your name. Just because you have the certificate, doesn't mean you still own the shares.
If the check went unclaimed for some reason (say the check never reached you because you moved), it would've gone to the state which would let you claim the money within certain number of years.

[unclaimed.org](https://www.unclaimed.org) and [missingmoney.com](https://www.missingmoney.com) are a good starting point where you can search the databases of multiple states (I think all 50 actually) and if a match is found, you can submit a claim with the particular state.